# Grammatical explanation for a phrase "do as you think fit"

Tags: grammar, phrases, expressions

"Do as you think fit."

I feel like it's a incomplete sentence.

Shouldn't there be "it" put before "fit"?

Comment: I can't offer a grammatical analysis, but I can tell you the sentence is not incomplete, and categorically that no, there should be not *it* before *fit*. Though a case could be made that an *is* (not *it*) has been elided there.

Comment: Why do you think there should be an 'it'? What research have you done to look for an answer? For example, what definitions have you found for 'fit' which makes you think it needs another word added?

Comment: Sorry I don't know why I thought "it" would help here. English too difficult for me. Thank you all the same.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the cited version, but to my ear it would also be "grammatical" to include ***it*** AND/OR ***is*** after ***think***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*think fit* (alternatively *see fit*) is a [set phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_phrase) meaning *to regard as proper or appropriate (Collins [1](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/think-fit)), or desirable ([2](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/see-fit)).

Set phrases can seem to violate a grammar rule, but once you recognize them as such, you can try substituting their definition to see how they work.

> Do as you think fit. -> Do as you desire.

Comment: It seems to be that "do as you think desirable" and "do as you desire" are a little different.  What I might desire to do (keep some found money) and what I think desirable (return the money) are different.

Comment: @Xanne: I agree. A better translation would be "Do what you think is best"