# What do "Ever thought" and "Fit to exact" mean?

Tags: meaning, sentence

What does "thought fit"  mean?
Full context:

> *"None of those ancients **ever thought fit to exact** the money as payment for his wisdom or to give exhibitions among people of various
>   places."* - Hippias Major page 387 Chapter 13

The context is when Socrates talks about 2 pre-sophists Gorgias and Protagoras, but I have no idea about the meaning of this sentence for my English is not able me understanding it,  someone please help! Thank a lot!

Comment: "...ever [thought fit] [to exact] the money ..." You're parsing it incorrectly.

Comment: Accents? Hippies? Should be "ancients" and "Hippias", I think.

Comment: The multi-word verb _think fit [to]_ is addressed [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/382116/grammatical-explanation-for-a-phrase-do-as-you-think-fit).

Comment: It means they did not think it was appropriate to charge money for their wisdom.

Answer (score 1):

> None of those ancients ever thought fit to exact the money as payment for his wisdom

You're parsing the sentence wrongly. Parse it like this:

> [None of those ancients] ever [thought fit to] [exact] [the money] [as payment for his wisdom]

- ["thought fit to"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/382116/grammatical-explanation-for-a-phrase-do-as-you-think-fit) = "thought it was a good idea to" (link from Edwin Ashworth's comment)
- "[exact](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exact) the money" = "demand money" (in the sense of charging a customer, not begging for money)

Adding in those substitutions:

> [None of those ancients] ever [thought it was a good idea to] [demand money] [as payment for his wisdom]

In other words, the thought had never occurred to any of the ancients to charge people for giving them wisdom.